# Get a linear date Shiny slider input to "stick" on only specified irregular dates

Tags: r, shiny

I am using a Shiny date slider but there are only certain dates with observations. When the user moves the slider I would like it to jump to the nearest observation date when released.  I could use an index value to step through each observation but I want to preserve the spatial appearance of a linear timeline.

My hunch is to render the slider on the fly, updating the `value` parameter with the nearest available observation date whenever the `inputId` of the slider changes, but this creates a circular argument with `inputId` and `value` parameters.

The example below shows my attempt to avoid this circularity.  Note that if you comment out `value = ifelse(length(nearest_date()) > 0,nearest_date(),min(date_vec)),` and replace it with `value = min(date_vec),` the code runs fine (just not what I want).

```r
library(shiny)
#> Warning: package 'shiny' was built under R version 4.1.3

date_vec <- as.Date("2022-01-01") +
  cumsum(round(runif(10, 1, 20)))

ui <- fluidPage(uiOutput("jumpySlider"),
                mainPanel(textOutput("this_date"),
                          textOutput("desired_date")))

server <- function(input, output) {
  nearest_date <- reactive({
      date_vec[which.min(abs(as.numeric(input$date) - as.numeric(date_vec)))]
  })

  output$jumpySlider <- renderUI({
    sliderInput(
      "date",
      "Date",
      min = min(date_vec),
      max = max(date_vec),
      # value = min(date_vec),
      # PROBLEM LINE
      value = ifelse(length(nearest_date()) > 0,nearest_date(),min(date_vec)),
      animate = animationOptions(interval = 100)
    )
  })

  output$this_date <- renderText({
    paste("Slider Date:", format.Date(input$date))
  })
  output$desired_date <- renderText({
    paste("Desired Date:", format.Date(nearest_date()))
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Shiny applications not supported in static R Markdown documents

<sup>Created on 2022-07-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using `observe` to update the `sliderInput` to the closest date. The `sliderInput` "jumps" to the closest date after the input from the user.

```
library(shiny)

set.seed(2022)
date_vec <- as.Date("2022-01-01") + cumsum(round(runif(10, 1, 20)))

ui <- fluidPage(
        sliderInput(
        "date",
        "Date",
        min = min(date_vec),
        max = max(date_vec),
        value = min(date_vec)
        ),
        mainPanel(
          textOutput("this_date")
          )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observe({
    req(input$date)
     updateSliderInput(session, "date", 
       value = date_vec[which.min(abs(date_vec - input$date))])
  })
  
  output$this_date <- renderText({
    paste("Slider Date:", format.Date(input$date))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: You've got to the main issue. I learned about updateSliderInput and req, which I didn't know before.  Thanks, Ronak. But if you look at the OP, I have set animate=TRUE.  If I run your code with animation, the slider ping-pongs because I am testing for the absolute closest date.  Your code should work with a test for next-date instead of closest-date.  I am trying to figure that out now.

Comment: A-Ha! this does the trick  updateSliderInput(session, "date",
                      value = min(date_vec[which(input$date <= date_vec)]))